# Fill Phaser TileLayer with Data

Tags: html, html5-canvas, webgl, phaser-framework

With Phaser there is the possibility to to create TileMaps which are pretty neat so I would love to use them. I can generate the required array of tile "data" that you would usually initiate the tilemaps with but since I generate them on the fly I can't use like `game.load.tilemap(key, url, null, Phaser.Tilemap.TILED_JSON)` to initiate my tilemap. I am looking for a way to write tiles from an array or in the best case to just put an array of data to the tilemap API and it draws the tiles.

If you need any more information, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call directly [Phaser.TilemapParser.parseTiledJSON()](https://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.TilemapParser.html#parseJSON), it's a static method: just build the right object and pass it as an argument.